# snap firefox over ssh X11-forwarding doesn't use X user's pulseaudio daemon

Tags: firefox, pulseaudio, snap, x11-forwarding, pipewire

I run multiple instances of applications, including firefox, under different user accounts, all displaying to the same X server.

In the past, as the X user I just did the equivalent of: `ssh -X user2@localhost firefox`

Since switching to 22.04 with the snap firefox, firefox no longer plays audio. (To be clear, firefox running directly as the X user works fine, but no longer any instances started over ssh as user2.)

Initially, I couldn't even get firefox to run over ssh but I found hints that led me to cargo-cult these commands into user2's `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
```

The first line allows the snap to talk to the X server; the second removes the slow startup and restores downloading ability (downloads would simply report failure (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>), and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> save-as file chooser dialog never appeared).

However, while video now displays fine, audio still does not work. When run as a different user2 over ssh (to localhost), the snap version of firefox either doesn't find, or doesn't connect to, the pulseaudio daemon run by the X user.

I found a suggestion that starting firefox as:

```
echo 'export PULSE_SERVER=<PATH>; /snap/firefox/current/user/lib/firefox/firefox' |\
snap run --shell firefox
```

would fix the problem but this made no difference in my case.

I set `<PATH>` to be `unix:/var/tmp/pulse-socket`.

(I think) I configured the X user's pulseaudio daemon to also listen there:

```
pacmd load-module module-native-protocol-unix auth-anonymous=1 socket=/var/tmp/pulse-socket
```

`pax11publish` shows sensible info.

Running non-snap applications (such as `mpv video.mp4` or the tar version of `zoom`) as user2 over ssh works fine with no further config (I guess they find and use the X root window properties).

I don't know much about pulseaudio (and even less about pipewire, for which I see some configuration inside the firefox snap). And I know next to nothing about dbus.

---

Is there a simple way to make the "remote" firefox snap use the X user's pulseaudio daemon?

Comment: Oops. I just realised the snap can't actually **access** the socket in `/var/tmp` even though it can see it. If I add a hardlink in `~user2`, set PULSE_SERVER to point to that, and do the `snap run` command, sound does work. Huzzah. But is there a nicer method?

Comment: Typically that should go in ~/.bashrc instead of .bash_aliases.  Also, it's possible that that link might cause a security hole with the way apparmor sanboxes snaps...

Answer (score 0):

The missing piece of the puzzle was permissions on `/dev/snd/*`

My configuration is now:

**as root:**

```
setfacl -m u:user2:rw  /dev/snd/[chpst]*
```

**as user2:**

```
export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
```

After this `firefox` plays audio correctly.